# Transform pandas series of serialized json into pandas series of dicts

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following pandas series:

```
>>>df.A.head()

0    {"Date_": "2022-06-01T01:00:00+05:30", "submit...
1    {"Growth": [{"textField": "", "Change_Size": "...
2    {"submit": true, "HSI_Tag": "xyz...
3    {"submit": true, "HSI_Tag": "xyz...
4    {"submit": true, "roleList": "xy...
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Every item in the series is a serialized JSON
item. I would like to turn every item into a dictionary. I am trying to do the following, but I get an error:

```
for i in range(len(df.A)):
    df.A.iloc[i] = json.loads(df.A.iloc[i])
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-9b4e8d4e6d76> in <module>
      1 for i in range(len(df.A)):
----> 2     df.A.iloc[i] = json.loads(df.A.iloc[i])

C:\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    188             key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    189         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
--> 190         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    191
    192     def _validate_key(self, key, axis):

C:\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
    640                 # setting for extensionarrays that store dicts. Need to decide
    641                 # if it's worth supporting that.
--> 642                 value = self._align_series(indexer, Series(value))
    643
    644             elif isinstance(value, ABCDataFrame):

C:\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _align_series(self, indexer, ser, multiindex_indexer)
    774
    775         elif is_scalar(indexer):
--> 776             ax = self.obj._get_axis(1)
    777
    778             if ser.index.equals(ax):

C:\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_axis(self, axis)
    376
    377     def _get_axis(self, axis):
--> 378         name = self._get_axis_name(axis)
    379         return getattr(self, name)
    380

C:\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_axis_name(cls, axis)
    373                 pass
    374         raise ValueError('No axis named {0} for object type {1}'
--> 375                          .format(axis, type(cls)))
    376
    377     def _get_axis(self, axis):

ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'type'>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: please provide a fully reproducible input (`df.head().to_dict('list')`) and the matching expected output

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Have not checked it, but you should use `df.A.apply(func)` to convert them into a dict. Instead of using the manual for loop. Will you please try that and get back with it?

Comment: try just iterating the dataframe first. Dont use the loads part. Do you have problems just by for i in range(len(df.A)):
    df.A.iloc[i] ? If not it means that not everything is in json

Comment: @minattosama everything is json, that's a fact

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it eventually with *[apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)* and a lambda like this:

```
df.A = df.A.apply(lambda x: json.loads(x))
```